# Android show view and hide keyboard at same time. Weird behaviour

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a custom view that could show a view in same space that should be soft keyboard native for android.

I need to having the keyboard opened, click in a button, hide the keyboard and shows other view in same place that keyboard be/was.

I have that implemented right now just with a hide keyboard and show custom view but has a weird behavior and min lag and overlapping.

Has someone implemented a similar stuff?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/4790490) might be helpful

Comment: Did you figure it out? I need to do the same.

Comment: post some code in the question

Comment: @RahulKhurana Sample minimal project reproducing the issue is located at https://github.com/DanPetras/keyboard-test

Comment: hi @sidon i have posted my answer. Please check

Comment: So, did my answer works? @colymore

Comment: Yes, i've marked as resolved :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the Github project and found the bug and I have fixed that bug with the following code:

```
if (isRedPanelVisible()) {
    showRedPanel(false);
    showKeyboard(true, new KeyboardCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyboardDone(boolean isVisible) {

        }
    });
}
if (KeyboardVisibilityEvent.isKeyboardVisible(TestActivity.this)) {
    hideKeyboard(TestActivity.this);
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showRedPanel(true);
        }
    }, 100);
```

Note: You just have to put this in TestActivity.java under button's click event and Remove the previous code.

> What I did

if your **readPanel is visible** then I called the `showRedPanel` to `false` and try to open the keyboard.

After that I have added a check for Keyboard's visibility event and if keyboard is visible I called `hideKeyboard` to make keyboard go away and call `showReadPanel` with `true` after a delay of **100 ms**

> Code: hideKeyboard

```
public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        try {
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However this solution only fixes the issue that keyboard and red panel are displayed at the same time. The other issue (when neither of them is displayed) is still present - and even more visible. I think, the key question is how to switch red panel and keyboard visibility in single layout/render pass so they are swapped seamlessly.

Comment: In that case you need to render [KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) and redPanel layout in single layout container.

Answer (score 3):

So what happens in your code is that:
Tell system to close the keyboard **->** Show red panel with a small delay **->** Red panel is shown before keyboard closing **->** Since keyboard mode is in `adjustResize` the red panel shown above keyboard **->** Keyboard get closed **->** Everything in place

**Try to change `windowSoftInputMode` in manifest from `adjustResize` to `adjustNothing`.**

Sadly keyboard in android doesn't work smoothly like in IOS, keyboard is handled by OS means you no control over it size, opening/closing animation and no callback! So the best way is to always show red panel and when needed Open keyboard on **top** of it.

Answer (score -2):

se the following functions to show/hide the keyboard:

```
/**
 * Hides the soft keyboard
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the soft keyboard
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this function, i need to coordinate with other view showing-hidding..

Comment: you can just pass view object

Comment: What? (10moretogo)